# Create a generic function to GET data using fetch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am trying to get my hands on vanilla JS.

I came across the fetch API that can be used to make calls to URL and I am wondering if I can make a generic function to be used across my application.

This is is the function I have currently

```
async function get(url){
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json()
      return data
}
```

I have worked with Fetch before but in react where I would call the `this.setState()` function inside the async function. 
The function above returns a promise and not the actual json data I should get from the URL. I completely understand why it does that.

I want to know if there is a way to make a generic function say function `myGet(url)` which when called returns the json object retrieved from the GET call and not the promise. 
Then I can call this function all across my application.

I don't want to write my rest of the code inside the .then() function after I get the response.

Comment: Why not `const result = await get(url);`?

Comment: Think about it, do you really want blocking calls all across your codebase or would you rather maintain the async nature?

Comment: the operation is async operation, you have to return a Promise from that function. You can use await to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking to write synchronous code with asynchronous functionality. As close as you can get with that is using async/await. You'll be able to get the JSON response without getting into `.then()` nesting hell.

```
// leave this as is
async function get(url){
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json()
      return data
}

// example function consuming the get method
async function doThings() {
  const googleData = await get('http://www.google.com');
  console.log(googleData); // this would output the actual JSON response (if real)
}
```

The key is denoting any ***consuming function*** as asynchronous as well. Anything other than this will involve you using `.then()` or some sort of callback hell. Async/await is definitely my preference even though it's just syntactical sugar for Promises.

Comment: Makes sense. So I basically made the function doThings and called the function in my script which produced results as required.
Thank you.